# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx on digitalocean

Tags: nginx

On digitalocean nginx server I ran following command on terminal

```
sudo chown -R user:user /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

Now after that I started facing 504 Gateway Time-out Error. I have to restart php5-fpm again and again after few minutes to fix this issue. But after few minuts it shows same 504 Gateway Time-out Error.

Please guide me how can I fix this issue.

Comment: The 504 error normally means the application is taking too long to respond. If it works fine at first but then stops working shortly thereafter, you could be running into a resource contention issue. Easy to confirm if you have sysstat installed on the server (check sar logs). If not, the droplet graphs might help you get a better picture.

Answer (score -1):

Increase `fastcgi` directive timeout:

```
server{
  # ...
  fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 60s;
  # ...
}
```